# Запускается пустая консоль после сборки приложения с использованием Pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt-designer, pyinstaller

Собрал программу на *Python* и *Qt Designer* через 
**`pyinstaller --onefile  main.py`**.

**`Запускается консоль пустая и уже после неё само окно приложения.`**

Как сделать так, что бы консоль не открывалась при запуске приложения? 
И сможет ли только  **файл.exe** работать на другом *ПК*, где не установлены *python* и библиотеки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете скрытие окно консоли повторно запустив команду 
`pyinstaller` и передать флаг конфигурации `-w`, `--noconsole` или `--windowed`
вместе со своим main.py

```
pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile  main.py
```

И сможет ли только файл .exe работать на другом ПК, где не установлены python и библиотеки?
я думаю, что да, но предлагаю вам это проверить самостоятельно и сообщить нам об этом в комментарии.

Comment: Qt либы инсталлер нормально собирает? Там 200 мегабайт)

Comment: @eri не 200, а 33

Comment: Ну значит нормально собирает. Это qtcore + qtgui примерно и выходит.